# Prove $[A, B] = I \implies [A,B^m] = mB^{m-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2\times 2$ real matrices and $[A,\,B] = AB-BA$.
Prove that if $[A,\,B] = I$ (identity matrix) then $[A,\,B^m] = mB^{m-1}$ for all positive integers $m$.

Answer (score 6):

Note first that$$[X,\,YZ]=XYZ-YZX=XYZ-YXZ+YXZ-YZX=[X,\,Y]Z+Y[X,\,Z].$$We can now proceed by induction; the cases $m\in\{0,\,1\}$ are trivial, and if $m=k$ works then $$[A,\,B^{k+1}]=[A,\,B^k]B+B^k[A,\,B]=kB^{k-1}B+B^kI=(k+1)B^k.$$

Answer (score 3):

First, notice that from the properties of the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)), we have that:

$$
\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)
$$
And:
$$
\text{Tr}(X+Y)=\text{Tr}(X)+\text{Tr}(Y)
$$

Thus:
$$
\text{Tr}([A, B])=\text{Tr}(AB)-\text{Tr}(BA) = 0
$$

But $\text{Tr}(I) = 2$, for the $2\times 2$ identity.

Hence the hypothesis $[A,B] = I$ is impossible.

Comment: No one required the characteristic of the field to be different from $2$; note that a direct proof of the claim above would work for infinite-dimensional operators, where traces are not defined for all bounded operators, and we get a contradiction assuming that $A,B$ are bounded.

Comment: I fail to understand your comment. The question states that A and B are 2x2 real matrices.

Comment: Right, sorry. I wanted to point out that while your argument works in this setting, it doesn’t “prove” the claim in other settings where the assumption aren’t this “obviously” contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Remark 1}$. Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ s.t.$AB-BA=I$.

Then $A=e^A$.

$\textbf{Remark 2}$. Let $A,B$ be linear operators in a normed vector-space of infinite dimension s.t. $AB-BA=I$.

Then $AB^m-B^mA=mB^{m-1}$ and, consequently, $A$ or $B$ is not continuous.