# Prove that if $AB - BA = I$ then $A^mB - BA^m = mA^{m-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question comes from an exercise in Shilov's *Linear Algebra*. His hint is to use induction, but I'm struggling to get anywhere. I looked through the book and couldn't find any theorem that seemed useful, so I'm guessing there is some sort of manipulation I must be missing? A good first step to take would be much appreciated.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Hint: $A^2B = A(AB) = A(AB-BA+BA) = A(I+BA) = A + ABA$.  Now do something similar to the second term.  This should let you see how to get from $m = 1$ to $m = 2$, from which you should be able to work out the induction.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3390022/11619)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the author suggests, we shall use induction.

The base case, i.e. $m = 1$ follows from the hypothesis. Suppose for $k\in \mathbb N$, $$A^kB - BA^k= kA^{k-1}$$
Multiplying throughout by $A$, we have
$$A^{k+1} B - ABA^{k} = kA^k$$
but $AB = BA + I$, so $$A^{k+1} B - (BA + I)A^k = kA^k$$
which on simplification yields,
$$A^{k+1} B - BA^{k+1} = (k+1)A^k$$
Therefore, by the principle of (weak) mathematical induction, we have $$A^mB - BA^m = mA^{m-1}$$ for all $m\in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

$AB=I+BA,$ so $A^2B=A+(AB)A=2A+BA^2.$ This gives you the proof when $m=2.$

Assume you has the proposition when $m=k-1,$ try to prove the case when $m=k$ by similar idea.

If you want to use induction to prove something, try to solve it in the simple case first. The idea in proving normal case will be implied in the simple one.